# High Performing Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a requirement to consume from a Kafka Topic. The Topic is provided by the producer team and we have no control on them. The producer publishes huge amount of messages which our consumer is unable to consume. However we only require 5-10% of the volume produced. Currently in Consumer we deserialize the message and based on certain attributes drop 90-95% of the messages. The consumer is behind 5-10L messages most of the time during the day. We even tried with 5 consumer and 30 threads in each consumer but not much success.

Is there any way we can subscribe Consumer to the Topic with some filter criteria so we only receive messages we are interested in.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to filter messages without consuming and even partially deserializing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Broker-Side filtering is not supported, though it has been discussed for a long time (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6020)

You mentioned that you do not control the producer. However, if you can get the producer to add the attribute you filter by to a message header, you can save yourself the parsing of the message body. You still need to read all the messages, but the parsing can be CPU intensive, so skipping that helps with lag.

Comment: Honestly, I wish there was a 'header-only' consumer. This use case shows up so many times.